# sed to replace ip address string with an array

Tags: ssh, sed

I need to enclose `network_ip_v4_address` which are not enclosed as an array needs to be enclosed as array.

For eg. in my below code `"network_ip_v4_address":"20.38.32.202"` is not an array (is a string). This line has to changed as `"network_ip_v4_address":["20.38.32.202"]` but already which are enclosed in array should not be touched.

```
{
   "network_ip_v4_address":"20.38.32.202",
   "mac_address": "A0:12:34:45",
   "network_ip_v4_address": [
        "10.38.61.1",
        "10.38.32.1"
    ],i
   "network_gateway_address": [
        "10.38.62.1",
        "10.38.33.1"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example I think this works, with GNU sed:

```
sed -E '/4_address": \[/! s/(4_address":)([^,]*)/\1[\2]/' file
```